# Is there something like a fast access for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, display

When I need QGIS only to check up something, opening the QGIS application takes way to long (on my computer: 5 minutes from double cklick on the the project until ready).

I tried QGISCloud which doesn't work. Is there anything similar to just display data and maybe select different layers?

I have approximately 60 point vector layers with 30 objects each. Further a few point layers with 100-300 objects. Further, each point vector goes with a line vector (created with a query) to connect point and label. Last, there are few normal line vector layers and one google maps layer. The project itself is around 4mb.

---

it might work with the «Export to OpenLayers 3»-Plugin.

Comment: That completely depends on what you are trying to display. Just want to get a quick glimpse at a GeoTiff - almost any image viewer will work. We really need to know more about your data to be able to answer this question.

Comment: It could be an issue with how big your project is... 5 minutes is way longer than it takes QGIS to open to a blank project on my machine. Does the project you're opening already have lots of layers in the contents? How long does it take to just open QGIS (not an existing `.qgs` project)?

Comment: as per alpha-beta-soup suggestion, just open qgis, then open your project. It may not open any faster, but at least you'll see the progress. If you have a large number of plugins, also try **qgis --noplugins**, might be handy if memory is tight.

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup: you're right. A blank project takes 10sec max. So I assume it is because of the database.

Comment: @Steven Kai. I have no more than 10 plugins. This isn't a large number, though?

Comment: @Kersten: I added some information above. I think of sth where I can check or uncheck the layers but no more. Similar to the "old" google maps engine for user without modification authorisation.

Comment: The Export to OpenLayers 3 plugin is no longer available, having been merged into qgis2web. That would be an option.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the **QGIS Browser** for your version of QGIS which (as it says) mainly allows you to browse through your shapefiles by accessing their Metadata and attributes. As it is a browser, it won't load the analytical tools or plugins. It also provides a preview for displaying:

[image: QGIS Browser]

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Joseph: Does this also work when data is in postGIS? I can choose the postGIS tables but I have specific request (e.g. "only area=1")

Comment: @kevkev - Unfortunately I cannot test that (I receive errors for some reason) so I cannot confirm it. There is a search option available when you click the _PostGIS_ tab and tick the **Search options**. So maybe if you include your expression, it might filter it out...? Apologies for not giving you a definitive answer.